# Getting square using try and catch

Tags: java

So i'm just a grade 10 student and we were doing this program where we would get the square but it would reject negative numbers using try and catch my prof said I was the only one close to the output but ran out of time.

this is the code.
it displays the answer but doesnt reject negative numbers nor display "Only positive numbers"
help pls :D

```
import java.util.*;
public class MySquare{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int num;
        int square;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input a number.");
        num = s.nextInt();
           square = num * num;
        System.out.println("Square: " + square);
        try{

        if( num <0){


           throw new InputMismatchException("Only Positive Numbers!");
        }
    }catch (InputMismatchException e){

    }
```

Comment: write if condition before calculating square.

Answer (score 0):

Your catch block is empty - that's a very bad idea.  Never do that.

At a minimum, you should add this:

```
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

One word of advice: Learn and follow a rigorous code style.  Placement of braces, names, etc.  are very important.

Answer (score 0):

You were already close. Try this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int num;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input a number.");

    try{ // try catch should surround s.nextInt, too
        num = s.nextInt(); // read the input

        if( num <0){
            throw new InputMismatchException("Only Positive Numbers!");
        }
        // this part isnt reached in case of a negative number
        int square = num * num;
        System.out.println("Square: " + square);
    }catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("invalid input! " + e.getMessage()); // catch the exception and print its message (e.g. "Only Positive Numbers!" when a negative number is entered)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **InputMismatchException** use **IllegalArgumentException()**

**code refactored**

```
import java.util.*;
public class MySquare{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int num;
        int square;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input a number.");
        num = s.nextInt();
        try {
            if(num < 0){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only Positive Numbers!");
            }
            square = num * num;
            System.out.println("Square: " + square);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}